# wrong index in bar plot in mathplotlib

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

If i setup my bar plot like this, the index is correct reset to seconds (`set_index`, line 1).

But somehow by creating the stacked bar plot (line 4), this index (by seconds) is not used, the index is plotted with number of records.

At line 5, the correct index (seconds) is used.

How can I repair the bar plot index to 'seconds'?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[['seconds', 'marker', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3']]
df = df.set_index('seconds')
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, alpha=set_alpha)
plt.plot(df.index, df['data1'], linestyle='solid', color='blue', alpha=0.4, label='data1')
plt.show()
```

Data example:

```
seconds,marker,data1,data2,data3,data4
0,B,0,0,0,0
59,C,42,8,369000,0
74,B,42,8,369000,283041
121,B,42,8,369000,283041
179,B,42,8,369000,283041
239,B,42,8,369000,283041
304,B,42,8,369000,283041
360,B,42,8,369000,283041
377,A,42,8,369000,283041
420,B,42,8,369000,283041
493,B,42,8,369000,283041
540,B,42,8,369000,283041
600,B,42,8,369000,283041
659,B,42,8,369000,283041
719,B,64,8,412000,283041
780,B,64,8,412000,283041
840,B,64,8,412000,283041
880,A,64,8,412000,283041
900,B,64,8,412000,283041
961,B,64,8,412000,283041
1020,B,64,8,412000,283041
1079,B,64,8,412000,283041
1141,B,64,8,412000,283041
1200,B,64,8,412000,283041
1260,B,64,8,412000,283041
1320,B,64,8,412000,283041
1365,A,64,8,412000,283041
1382,B,64,8,412000,283041
1440,B,64,8,412000,283041
1498,B,64,8,412000,283041
1559,B,64,8,412000,283041
1621,B,64,8,412000,283041
1679,B,64,8,412000,283041
1740,B,64,8,412000,283041
1800,B,42,8,369000,283041
1830,A,42,8,369000,283041
1867,B,42,8,369000,283041
1921,B,42,8,369000,283041
1979,B,42,8,369000,283041
2040,B,42,8,369000,283041
2099,B,42,8,369000,283041
2159,B,42,8,369000,283041
2220,B,42,8,369000,283041
2272,A,42,8,369000,283041
2288,B,42,8,369000,283041
2341,B,42,8,369000,283041
2400,B,42,8,369000,283041
2460,B,42,8,369000,283041
2520,B,42,8,369000,283041
2579,B,42,8,369000,283041
2640,B,42,8,369000,283041
2700,B,42,8,369000,283041
2720,A,42,8,369000,283041
2759,B,42,8,369000,283041
2833,B,28,14,248000,260096
2880,B,28,14,248000,247808
2940,B,14,28,124000,123904
3000,B,0,42,0,0
3060,B,0,42,0,0
3120,B,0,42,0,0
3136,A,0,42,0,0
3180,B,0,42,0,0
3251,B,0,42,0,0
3267,D,0,42,0,0
3300,B,0,42,0,0
3359,B,0,42,0,0
3419,B,0,42,0,0
3538,B,0,0,0,0
3599,B,0,0,0,0
3643,C,140,4,1260000,0
```

Comment: Do you mind providing a [mcve]?

Comment: `ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, alpha=set_alpha)` you don't specify where the bar heights should come from here

Comment: Supposing that `df['seconds']` is numerical, in your call to `df.plot()`, pandas uses a categorical index, while `plt.plot` would use the numeric values. This would lead to a mismatch.t

Comment: Great point from @JohanC -- bar plots have categorical axes. Line plots (generally) have numeric axes

Comment: @PaulH:  See [df.plot.bar](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) `y: If not specified, all numerical columns are used`.  Anyway, without reproducible test data there are too many unknowns to properly solve this question.

Comment: Making a stacked bar plot with such a huge difference between `data1` and `data3` will totally swamp the small bars. With the given data, you can't combine the categorical bar plot with the numeric line plot.  A trick would be to convert the `seconds` column to strings (before setting it as index).  `df['seconds'] = df['seconds'].astype(str)`.

Comment: With `df['seconds'].astype(str)` the index from `plt.plot` seems to fit to the bar plot with `df.plot`.  But I need it the other way around, is that possible? When add the xticks labels, the bar plot does not fit to index.

Comment: @JohanC insted of xticks, i need to `use ax.xaxis.set_major_locator` and `MinuteLocator`? could you suggest a locator formatting? because with the time index in "seconds" I don't get any useful result

Comment: You just have seconds from the experiment's start. You'd need matplotlib's time format to be able to use `MinuteLocator` etc.  To position the bars non-categorical, you can use matplotlib's bars.

Comment: @JohanC Im confused as to whether it's still a data index issue or now a formatting question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676863/format-index-at-stacked-bar-plot). Maybe you can check out the current version and if necessary I can merge this questions to one. If you could add an example, that would be very nice, thanks!